# Digging without cards

Tags: thebes

Can someone dig without any books of knowledge using only shovels (therefore taking out only a few tokens)? If not, why?

Comment: Please ask your second question as a separate question. The format of this site doesn't work well for having multiple questions in 1 unless they are closely related. You can question to remove the second part.

Comment: I have removed the second question. You can still get it out of your revision history by visiting the [edited X time ago](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/33515/revisions) link at the bottom of your post. Please do ask it separately as Gendolkari requested.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dig unless you have at least 1 point of specialized knowledge in that region. From the rules, page 5:

> If the player fulfills the requisites below, he can execute an excavation.
>
> The minimum requirement
>
> > • The player has a valid excavation permission for the area.
> >
> > • The player has at least **1 point of specialized knowledge** for the excavation area, either from a researcher card or found item.